# Java/JAXB: Unmarshall XML with inheritance

Tags: java, jaxb, hierarchy, unmarshalling

I need help to annotate my classes so I will be able to map correctly all the attributes/elements to the right classes.

I have the following xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceList xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com CM.xsd" xmlns="http://www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Resource xsi:type="customField" lastModifiedDate="2001-12-17T09:30:47.0Z" dataType="Alphanumeric" required="false" id="customField/1" expiryDate="2001-12-17T09:30:47.0Z" expiryReminder="2" targetClass="copyrightHolder" effectiveDate="2001-12-17T09:30:47.0Z" order="0" maximumLength="0" name="a" minimumLength="0" defaultValue="String"/>
    <Resource xsi:type="contact" phoneMobile="String" lastModifiedDate="2001-12-17T09:30:47.0Z" type="a" id="contact/1" phoneOffice="String" email="x@x" expiryDate="2001-12-17T09:30:47.0Z" expiryReminder="2" phoneWork="String" effectiveDate="2001-12-17T09:30:47.0Z" name="a" notify="true"/>
    <Resource xsi:type="document" lastModifiedDate="2001-12-17T09:30:47.0Z" id="document/1" filePath="/docs/document1"/>
    <Resource xsi:type="copyrightHolder" lastModifiedDate="2001-12-17T09:30:47.0Z" type="a" id="copyrightHolder/1" expiryDate="2001-12-17T09:30:47.0Z" expiryReminder="2" effectiveDate="2001-12-17T09:30:47.0Z" name="a" affiliation="a">
        <ExternalId>String</ExternalId>
        <ContactId>contact/1</ContactId>
        <DocumentId>document/1</DocumentId>
        <CustomFieldValue value="String" customFieldId="customField/1"/>
        <Address>String</Address>
    </Resource>
</ResourceList>
```

I would like in the end of the process to have a list with objects belonging to the custom field class, contact class, copyright etc.

Here´s how the model is designed.

```
@XmlSeeAlso({CopyrightHolder.class})
public class AbstractResource {
    private String name;
    private Date creationDate;
    private Date effectiveDate;
    private Date expiryDate;
    private Long dealExpiryReminder;
    private String id;
    private String lastModifiedDate;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public Date getEffectiveDate() {
        return effectiveDate;
    }

    public void setEffectiveDate(Date effectiveDate) {
        this.effectiveDate = effectiveDate;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public Date getExpiryDate() {
        return expiryDate;
    }

    public void setExpiryDate(Date expiryDate) {
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public Long getDealExpiryReminder() {
        return dealExpiryReminder;
    }

    public void setDealExpiryReminder(Long dealExpiryReminder) {
        this.dealExpiryReminder = dealExpiryReminder;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(String lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }

}



public class CoreResource extends AbstractResource{

    private List<String> documentIds;
    private List<String> contactIds;
    private String externalId;
    private List<CustomFieldValue> customFieldValues;

    @XmlElement
    public List<String> getDocumentIds() {
        return documentIds;
    }

    public void setDocumentId(List<String> documentIds) {
        this.documentIds = documentIds;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public List<String> getContactIds() {
        return contactIds;
    }

    public void setContactId(List<String> contactId) {
        this.contactIds = contactId;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getExternalId() {
        return externalId;
    }

    public void setExternalId(String externalId) {
        this.externalId = externalId;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public List<CustomFieldValue> getCustomFieldValues() {
        return customFieldValues;
    }

    public void setCustomFieldValue(List<CustomFieldValue> customFieldValues) {
        this.customFieldValues = customFieldValues;
    }

}



@XmlRootElement(name="ResourceList", namespace="http://www.example.com")
public class ResourceList {

    private List<AbstractResource> resourceList;


    public Resource[] getResource() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Resource", namespace="http://www.example.com")
    public List<AbstractResource> getResourceList() {
        return resourceList;
    }


    public void setResourceList(List<AbstractResource> resourceList) {
        this.resourceList = resourceList;
    }

}


public class CopyrightHolder extends CoreResource {

    private String address;
    private String affiliation;

    @XmlElement
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getAffiliation() {
        return affiliation;
    }

    public void setAffiliation(String affiliation) {
        this.affiliation = affiliation;
    }

}
```

When I ingest the xml, I get a list of AbstractResources, as expected, however I wanted the objects to be of his xml type. In this xml the 3rd element of the AbstractResource would be a Copyright Holder, the 2nd would be a Document and so on.

Is it possible to achieve that using only annotations? If not, how would I do that?

Thanks

Comment: The following should help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply Blaise. I looked into the blog and I didn´t find the unmarshall section. Could you please provide help as how I could unmarshall the xml to the correct java classes?